# How to install Git on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, sudo, git

When I run this command:

```
apt-get install git-core
```

It shows:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: plzz help me whtat to do

Comment: have you tried running with `sudo` as in `sudo apt-get install git-core`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefix the command with `sudo`. This gives you Administrative permissions for one command (runs it as the `root` user). You will be prompted for your user password.

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

More information on `sudo` [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

**Note:** You may also temporarily log in as `root` by typing `sudo su`

[image: Install via the software center]

**UPDATE**

Since the OP posted new information with a different error:

Only one instance of the package manager/updater can be running at one time. Make sure you have no other terminals trying to install software, or that your Software Updater isn't trying to install updates. Best way to make sure of this if you're not sure is to restart, then run the command in the terminal before you do anything else.

**UPDATE 2**

`git-core` is now an obsolete package in the PPA. The package has been renamed to simply `git`. I have updated my answer and link accordingly.

Comment: nothing happening...

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing Happening"? Are you getting the same error? Are you getting something else? If so, edit your question and post the new results.

Comment: manu@manu-G31M-ES2L:~$ sudo apt-get install git-core
[sudo] password for manu: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: @ManojChauhan Check my edit

Comment: thanxx  its working ..